# How to make div suddenly show if JavaScript is disabled even if page has already been opened

Tags: javascript

I know how to display content if JavaScript is disabled, but what I want to do is make a div suddenly appear even if the page is open at the time of JavaScript being disabled.

1. The page is opened.
2. The user goes to browser settings and disables JavaScript.
3. A div shows without refreshing the page.

How can I do this? I've seen other sites do this but I looked at their JavaScript files and didn't find anything in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. The user will just have to accept that if they turn off JavaScript, they'll have to refresh to get the gracefall fallback.

Comment: @Polynomial - OP says: "I've seen other sites do this". It would be good to see links to such sites.

Comment: Can you point to an example of this?

Comment: @j08691 I forgot what site it was... I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using CSS animations. They're [not supported everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), but I can't think of any alternative.

This hides your message by giving it a `font-size` of `0`, which is reset to `100%` after a delay of one second. Every half-second the JavaScript restarts the animation by switching to a dummy animation which keeps the element hidden. ([Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PcJqm/3/))

#### HTML

```
<div id="noscript-message">
    Please enable JavaScript to use this page.
</div>

<div>
    Spiffy JavaScript app here!
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#noscript-message {  
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: delayedDisplay;
    color: blue;
}

@-webkit-keyframes delayedDisplay {
    0% { font-size: 0;}
    99% { font-size: 0;}
    100% { font-size: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes delayedDisplay_dummy {
    0% { font-size: 0; }
    100% { font-size: 0; }
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var message = document.getElementById("noscript-message");

setInterval(function() {
    message.style.webkitAnimationName = "delayedDisplay_dummy";
    setTimeout(function() {
        message.style.webkitAnimationName = "delayedDisplay";
    }, 0);
}, 500);
```

You would need to duplicate all of the `webkit` prefixed properties with the other vendor prefixes; I've omitted them here for clarity.

Comment: Wow, it works! Most users will most likely be using CSS3 browsers, so thanks so much, this is perfect!

Comment: Neat trick. I mean, it's ugly as hell, but does the job well on supporting browsers.

Comment: In addition to what @Polynomial says, this looks like way too much work for most sites. I find the use case somewhat implausible (detecting that user disabled javascript on the fly) and am assuming the OP saw something different.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not possible, not without refreshing the page, at least not using just HTML and Javascript. The behaviour you are describing is not in any standard, so different browsers may act differently once a user has selected to disable javascript.

The normal mechanism as a developer would be use a [`<noscript>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-noscript-element.html) element. Most browsers will display this if the page was loaded and javascript was disabled. Some browsers *may* display it also if the page loaded and the user then disabled javascript.

When scripting is disabled, the contents of this element comes up once the page is refreshed.

Comment: Can you verify that this works with steps 2 and 3? Didn't work for me in Chrome.

Comment: @amnotiam - Answer amended. I don't believe it is possible _without_ a refresh (or is at least browser dependent).

Comment: I was using Chrome when I disabled JavaScript and was on a login page for something (I forgot what site it was) and when I was on the page all of a sudden a div appeared so that made me look at the source and the JavaScript files and I couldn't find anything. I am trying to find the site so you can see it.

Comment: @Nathan - It is entirely possible that Javascript was still running on _that_ page. Disabling javascript probably only work on newly loaded pages.

Comment: Yeah. @JeremyBanks' answer is perfect. Although it won't work in some browsers, it'll work in modern browsers at least.

Comment: @Nathan - Assuming that disabling javascript immediately stops javascript in currently loaded pages, yes. This may not be the case for all browsers (modern or not).

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `<div>` inside a `<noscript>` element, and then use CSS to animate its opacity:

```
@-webkit-keyframes showme {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes showme {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes showme {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#box {
     -webkit-animation: showme 5s;
     -moz-animation:    showme 5s;
     -ms-animation:     showme 5s;
}
```

...Of course, browser support would be an issue.